# Standalone class and Cross referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, standalone, xr

Is the standalone package compatible with the crossref (xr) package? This has been asked [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472079/cross-referencing-and-standalone-class), but the answer does not work for me.

MWE:
main.tex

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}

An equation
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:test_eq}
  a=b+c
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includestandalone[mode=build]{sub}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

sub.tex

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[main::]{main}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle]
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    % Place nodes
\begin{scope}
  % title
    \node [block]{Reference to equation Eq.~(\ref{main::eq:test_eq}) };
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Reference to equation does not work. Compiling sub.tex directly works fine[image]