# Externalize PGF file that includes a cross-reference

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing, standalone, matplotlib, externalize

I have some figures as PGF files that include cross-references in them. Each time I compile my main document, these figures are recompiled too. Therefore I would like to externalize these figures.

The problem is that if externalize through the standalone class, [as laid out in this answer by Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272813/externalize-pgf), the references do not work anymore.
(The problem of the standalone class not working with cross-references is also described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472079/cross-referencing-and-standalone-class) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540423/standalone-class-and-cross-referencing), no answers.)

The figures are made in Matplotlib via the PGF backend. An example of how to make such a figure with a cross-reference is given in [this blogpost by Matt Hancock](https://notmatthancock.github.io/2018/02/27/matplotlib-latex-reference.html), and I'll add that code here:

Matplotlib (Python) code:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('pgf')
pgf_with_custom_preamble = {
"text.usetex": True,    # use inline math for ticks
"pgf.rcfonts": False,   # don't setup fonts from rc parameters
"pgf.preamble": [
    "\\usepackage{amsmath}",         # load additional packages
]
}
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_custom_preamble)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
plt.plot(np.random.randn(10), label="Equation \\eqref{eq:foo}")
plt.grid(ls=":")
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.savefig("figure.pgf", bbox_inches="tight")
```

LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:foo}
    e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \resizebox{3in}{3in}{
        \input{figure.pgf}
    }
    \caption{This is the caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

How could I externalize this figure, whilst keeping the cross-reference in the figure working?

Comment: This problem has to do with preserving links when inserting pdfs -- which due to the nature of the pdf is not trivial. I had posted several questions related to this and sort of had a working solution, but can't find those questions at the moment.

Comment: @PeterGrill, do you maybe remember what tags you've given to those questions? (I couldn't find them in your questions tagged "pdf" or "pgfplot")

Comment: When externalizing as laid out in the quoted answer, you can load the package xr or xr-hyper for importing cross-referencing data from your main .tex-file to the standalone .tex. This way you can have values of counters of cross-ref'ed items of sectioning displayed correctly but you won't get hyperlinks to the cross-ref'ed items of sectioning because when compiling standalone .tex named destinations of main.tex/main.pdf are unknown and will be replaced by fixed-ones by pdfTeX. (A circumstance which drives me crazy and probably can be worked around going the dvi-route with grfpaste/dvipaste.)

Comment: @Spinbar: I will try to look for them again later this week. It was not specfic to pgfplots, but rather a generic question about inserting pdfs and maintaining links. I recall the answer had some javascript.

Comment: @Spinbar: Finally found the question. Reason I could not find it earlier was because I had offered a bounty on someone else's question that was similar, thus it did not show up under questions I had asked. Anyway, here is the reference [Merging multiple pdf files without breaking hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497624/4301).